# cannot override a css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I have this scenario that I don't understand in the default bootstrap css style sheet the label css is defined like this

```
label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Now I override this css in my own stylesheet which is rendered after the bootstrap like this

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #333;
}
```

Can someone explain me why is browser is still rendering as a `display:block`?? even if the styles are well defined are good rendered? here's the screen shoot the computed styles

[image]

Here's the proof of the override of the style

[image]

Update, this is how is rendered the stylesheets

[image]

Comment: because bootstrap is evil? Seriously, though, get away from bootstrap!

Comment: are you 100% bootstrap css isn't rendered AFTER your own CSS ? I see no better explanation as such...

Comment: Can you link us to an example of the problem?

Comment: Bootstrap is linked behind your stylesheet.

Comment: @jbutler483 Bootstrap is better looking and engineered than the vast majority of our developers put together on our own. There are reasons people use it extensively.

Comment: Just make jsfiddle...

Comment: cannot replicate the error in fiddle i'm using sass

Comment: @ceejayoz: bootstrap is [evil](http://css.dzone.com/articles/please-stop-using-twitter). [It](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/07/bootstraps-and-web-kits-enemy-or-efficient/) [is](http://blog.guy.ht/2012/02/Why-Twitter-Bootstrap-is-bad-for-the-internet/) [uneducational](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/06/04/twitter-bootstrap-why-you-should-not-use-it/) [and](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/10/25/bootstrap-markup-less/) [terrible](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bootstrap)

Comment: this is not the place to debate if bootstrap is good or bad, please keep in the question if it's possible

Comment: @jbutler483 The irony of a site that looks like http://blog.guy.ht/2012/02/Why-Twitter-Bootstrap-is-bad-for-the-internet/ hating on Bootstrap is truly remarkable.

Comment: @Jorge: would it be possible for you to improve the specificity of your selector?

Comment: already do it, no changes... even using important which is wrong but I wanted to know if I get some changes

Comment: Well I'm using sass too xD, pass the code maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import your CSS code after Bootstrap that way it will get overwritten.

As pointed out, you can just use "!important" however, this is usually bad practice.

Comment: As I explain in my question my stylesheet if after the bootstrap

Comment: Yeah, avoid !important as much as possible.  It shouldn't ever be necessary.

Comment: @Jorge : Can you show the html where you import both css stylesheets, please?

Comment: I updated my question, proving that the default style is override but not used

Comment: I know it's getting overwritten but what I want is the HTML code. You should go like this:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css"> and after that include your styles. This will automatically apply the latest imported CSS.

Comment: I updated my question again, so you could see how the stylesheets are defined in the markup, the last one is on where I made the changes